# Regular expression to make HTML input numeric only including negative values

Tags: jquery, regex

I have two text fields. One is only for integers and other is for any numeric value. Both should receive **negative** values also. My code is

```js
$(".numberOnly").on("keypress keyup blur", function(event) {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
  if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

$(".intOnly").on("keypress keyup blur", function(event) {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/-?\d+[^0-9]+/, ""));
  if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Float</span>
<input type="text" name="numeric" class='numberOnly'>
<div>Numeric values With Decimal Point </div>
<br/> <br/> <br/>

<span>Int</span>
<input type="text" name="numeric" class='intOnly'>
<div>Only integers (No decimal point) </div>
```

It is working OK for numeric values,  but not taking negative values. what changes I should do?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I think you are missing the '-' (minus) in your first regex. Since that is a special character within a regex group you should also escape it with a backslash. /[^0-9\.]/g should be /[^0-9\.\-]/g

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").on("keydown", function(e) {

  if(!((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106)
      || (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) 
      ||  $(this).val() === '' && e.keyCode === 189
      || e.keyCode == 8)) {
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: It taking only integers, no decimal points, no negative sign. Also arrow,home,end, delete keys are not working.